# jQuery selecting elements for preventDefault

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('input[name=boxes], .item_add a ').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 //do stuff inherent to both 
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the default action of scrolling when I click on a link `[.item add a]`, but still keep the default action of checking and unchecking a checkbox `input[name=boxes]` without breaking these two into seperate onclick functions?

Comment: What is the real reason for not using 2 functions?

Comment: @Esailija because **OP HAS SPOKEN**! (or not...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[name=boxes], .item_add a ').on('click', function(e) {
     if($(e.target).is('a')) e.preventDefault(); //if it is a link then prevent

     //do stuff inherent to both 
})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('input[name=boxes], .item_add a ').on('click', function(e) {
   this.tagName == 'A' && e.preventDefault();
   //do stuff inherent to both 
}
```

Comment: faaaancy ^_^. Why no `===`?

Comment: @Neal - What other value of `tagName` could possibly `==` A?

Comment: Ha, I have no idea. but I would usually do `===` anyway.

Comment: @Neal - I've seen this advice all over: *always* use `===`. I think that's unnecessary. If you know what you're doing, you can pick and choose.

Comment: @JosephSilber: the answer is, convenience and less confusion. The question is, why would you ever *not* use `===` unless you're doing some really scary.

Answer (score 1):

Check the target element

```
if($(this).is('.item_add a')) e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=boxes], .item_add a ').on('click', function(e) {
  if (this.tagName == "A"){
    e.preventDefault();
  }

//do stuff inherent to both 
}
```

Comment: `$(this)[0].tagName`? HAHAHAHA. You are funny!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it in one function, but do the check inside the function?

```
if(!$(this).is(':checkbox')) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name=boxes], .item_add a ').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).is(':checkbox') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    //do stuff inherent to both 
}
```

Comment: ehhhh. Not fancy enough for me.

Comment: @Neal it's early in the day to be drinking ;)